# How to configure RFlinter with GIT to run linter check automatically on robot file with every commit

Tags: python, github, robotframework

How to do configuration of RFlinter with GIT so that linter will run automatically with every commit.

Comment: This is described in publicly available git documentation. Why do you need help here? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: I have RFLinter library but what I need to change exactly I'm not able to do with that .Thats' why I asked this

Comment: _what_ are you not able to do? What have you tried? Also, is `RFLinter` your own custom library?

Comment: no RFlinter is not my custom lib.

Comment: So, what is `RFLinter`? Though, you still haven't answered the question of what you've tried. We can't tell from your question what you need help with. Creating hooks in git is well documented.

Comment: sorry my guess  I missed some setting on git hook .

Answer (score 0):

This can be achievable by configuring github hooks, you can take a help from [guykisel/pre-commit-robotframework-lint](https://github.com/guykisel/pre-commit-robotframework-lint)